# Как в bash вывести строку столбиком

Tags: bash

Собственно вопрос - есть переменная
 `var1 = 'APP=1' '|' 'APP=2' 'HOST=127.0.0.1' '|' 'HOST=127.0.0.2' 'DB_PORT=3306' '|' 'DB_PORT=3307' 'LOG=file' '|' 'LOG=file1'` Как добиться что бы при выводе `echo $var1` было не:

`APP=1 | APP=2 HOST=127.0.0.1 | HOST=127.0.0.2 DB_PORT=3306 | DB_PORT=3307 LOG_CHANNEL=file | LOG_CHANNEL=file1`

а:

```
APP=1                                                                                |  APP=2
HOST=127.0.0.1                                                                       |  HOST=127.0.0.2
DB_PORT=3306                                                                         |  DB_PORT=3307
LOG_CHANNEL=file                                                                     |  LOG_CHANNEL=file11
```

Спасибо за помощь. Сразу скажу что сравниваю файлы через diff - само по себе отрабатывается отлично - **diff -y --suppress-common-lines file1 file2** результат сохраняю в переменной - но почему то выводит строкой.

Comment: вопрос закрыт - echo "$var1"

Comment: Как вы в переменной сохраняете? `var="$(diff f1 f2)"`?

Comment: Закрыть вопрос можно несколькими способами: 1) удалить; 2) написать ответ и подтвердить его.

Comment: `DIFF=$(diff -y --suppress-common-lines f1 f2 | column -t)`
`echo "$DIFF"`